# Play Sound File from res/raw using MediaPlayer

Tags: android, audio, media-player

I want to play Sound Files from raw folder using `MediaPlayer` but I don't want to use `MediaPlayer.create()` method, since I want to play it multiple times and want to retain `MediaPlayer` object. I was successful in compiling the following code but it plays nothing and I can't hear any sound.

```
public void STARTSOUND(SOUND sound) throws IOException {
    switch(sound) {
        case SOUND_MENUBG:
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("R.raw.mainmenu");
            PLAYSOUND(uri);
            break;
    }
}

public void PLAYSOUND(Uri file) throws IOException {
    mPlayerLoopSound.setDataSource(GameManager.getInstance().getCurrentActivity(),file);
    mPlayerLoopSound.prepareAsync();
    mPlayerLoopSound.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            if (!mPlayerLoopSound.isPlaying()){
                mPlayerLoopSound.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
                //start the player
                mPlayerLoopSound.start();
            }
        }
    });     
}
```

The onPrepared() method never gets called.. 
Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: you will have to us eoncreate method..,like this  MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(FakeCallScreen.this, R.raw.mysoundfile);

Comment: @VinamraBhabal Are you running your code on actual device?

Comment: @ Kanwaljit Singh Yes...

Answer (score 0):

```
private void playButtonSound(final Context context, final int resourceId)
    {
        final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, resourceId);
        if (mediaPlayer != null)
        {
            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer)
                {
                    if (mediaPlayer != null)
                    {
                        mediaPlayer.stop();
                        mediaPlayer.release();
                        mediaPlayer = null;
                    }
                }
            });
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    }
```

Call this method like this.

```
playButtonSound(PopScreenActivity.this, R.raw.soundfilename);
```

Comment: I don't want to use create() method. Because using it multiple times will use more memory and Game Play gets issue. I want to retain Media Player object..

Comment: @VinamraBhabal if your sound file continues play then use mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);

Comment: otherwise use the service for this.

Comment: @ Zala Janaksinh I did this... But not working... I am getting error MediaPlayer(22853): error (1, -2147483648)....

Comment: I unable to solve this issue. so I changed my sound code and I got another issue... Please help me for this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22243303/mediaplayer-finalized-without-being-released-sound-is-getting-stop

Answer (score 0):

First, hopefully you're initializing your MediaPlayer with:

```
mPlayerLoopSound = new MediaPlayer();
```

Next, make sure you call:

```
mPlayerLoopSound.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

which:

> Sets the audio stream type for this MediaPlayer. See AudioManager for a list of stream types. Must call this method **before prepare() or prepareAsync()** in order for the target stream type to become effective thereafter.

Then, in your OnPreparedListener(), when onPrepared() is called, notice the parameter it has: `MediaPlayer mp`. This is the MediaPlayer that is ready for playback, so you can use it:

```
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    if(!mp.isPlaying()) {
        mp.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
        mp.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But this is also not working.. I am getting error MediaPlayer(22853): error (1, -2147483648). When am running code in Debug, my debugger call is not getting inside  mPlayerLoopSound.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener(){}...

Comment: @ Melquiades 
Same code as given above.... Nothing changed except added mPlayerLoopSound.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); before prepareAsync().

Comment: @VinamraBhabal The code in your question is not enough to judge why you're getting this error, include onCreate(), onPause(), onResume() at minimum.

Comment: Also, explain WHEN you're getting this error. Is it at the start of the app? After a button press? After sound is played? Etc...

Comment: @ Melquiades Now I updated my code. I am getting error after this two lines...

 `mPlayerLoopSound.setDataSource(GameManager.getInstance().getCurrentActivity(),file);
    mPlayerLoopSound.prepareAsync();`

My main issue is my call is not going in   `mPlayerLoopSound.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener()` method...


what to do for this

Comment: Pass getApplicationContext() to setDataSource() as first parameter.

Comment: Also, register OnErrorListener() and check what error you're getting, see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener.html

Comment: I unable to solve this issue. so I changed my sound code and I got another issue... Please help me for this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22243303/mediaplayer-finalized-without-being-released-sound-is-getting-stop